# Problem with showing AdMob banner in Xamarin.Froms

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, admob

I'm creating a mobile app, and I want to display add's under listview.

I tried to add ads in the same way as in this guide:
https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/

I also found information that I need to use test IDs:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/147590/xamarin-forms-admob-firebase-ads-not-show

But after all this, ads are not showing up anyway.

```
//MainActivity.cs - part of OnCreate()
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            string appId;

#if DEBUG
            appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"; //TEST ID
#else
            appId = "ca-app-pub-5217408998830230~3120971952"; //MY ID
#endif

            Android.Gms.Ads.MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, appId);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

```
//My view
        public ListOfUniversitiesPage()
        {
            SetAdId();
            InitializeComponent();
            SetUniversities();
        }


        private void SetAdId()
        {
            string adId;

#if DEBUG
            adId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
#else
            adId = "ca-app-pub-5217408998830230/2060183484";
#endif

            BindingContext = new
            {
                AdUnitId = adId
            };
        }
```

The application runs without a problem in debug and production mode, but I do not see the ad.

Comment: What does your Xamarin forms code look like for the page on which you were supposed to add the ad?

Comment: @Saamer I have <StackLayout><ListView>...</ListView><AdControl/></StackLayout>

AdControl looks the same as the one in the guide.

Comment: Is there an empty space for the ad? Did you test your app I'd with a browser to see if it works elsewhere? And is it not working on iOS and Android?

Comment: @Saamer Yes, there is a space. How can i test it with browser? Currently I only have an android project.

Comment: https://codepen.io/osvaldas/pen/XNmNQN/ I think you can use one of these to test your ad account. Not a 100% sure though

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be very close, but there could be a lot of reasons,

1. Try it with an appId that works like ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
2. Have you updated AdMob with your payment details and made sure that the ads are banner ads.
3. Check the status of your ads, they need to be active
4. I'm sure you used the correct Ad Unit Id, but give it 24 hours, because it could depend on your region's fill rate
5. Did you use a registered test device or an emulator?
6. Are you using a sample ad unit?

Here's some official [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) about it.

Comment: Hi.
1. I used this Id.
2. Yes, my account is activated.
3. I'm not sure how to do that.
4. Still nothing.
5. I use either emulator or device. (But i don't know how to get device ID)

Comment: Okey, i found where is a problem. There is a problem where with space (as u said). I set grid row height to Auto but it isn't set the height of row. If i set a static height it works. What should i do? 
And can you help me with getting device ID?

Comment: Yayy! OK I can't really tell what's wrong with your code without seeing the xaml layout because it could be a lot of things.
My guess is that your content doesn't fit in the space calculated by 1 star of space. Maybe your content is 300dp tall and 1 star is calculating to 280dp at runtime. Or you could have a grid inside your content that is doing something for size and positioning. Or you could have some code that is trying to micromanage the size and it fails before knowing the space allocated.
No way to tell since we can't see what that content is.

Comment: For device id, you can just console write the device ID in your oage. You might have to use a Xamarin Essentials package to make it easy

Comment: Ah thank you! * does not mean automatic - Star is not auto-exapanding to fit. It means one unit. If you have 4 rows they will all be the same height.
If you have a row of 1 star and row of 2start then the 2star row will be twice as tall as the 1star row. Try Auto if you want to to automatically size to fit. It might even be working on iOS, since that is more forgiving

Comment: Hi, When I set Height of ListView to auto it covers everything. Now i can't even see my SearchBar and Button. :-/

Comment: I also found that AdSize return height equal to -1 (I use AdSize.SmartBanner) but ad with still shows when value is absolute.
It only work when I set height of row with AdMobView.